# Storing/calling complex condition logic that doesn't suit values defined as ENUM

Tags: java

Say there's a hundred classes that describe different `Animals` (because so many have unique behavior logic...), and a few classes that describe `Biomes`.

I need a way to pre-compile a list of all animal classes that may be instantiated given a specific climate zone, or other factors.

Currently, in my real application I use an enum that lists all "animal types" and has a weighted random method to return the `.class` for that animal.

```
Class<? extends Animal> cl = AnimalType.random().getClass();
if( cl != null ){
    e = cl.newInstance();
    // do stuff
}
```

However, the enum will no longer suffice because I need to add several methods for checking different conditions. The animal class can provide an array of acceptable temperatures, or land types, or other conditions.

I was thinking of a factory-type pattern or simply keeping that logic in the Animal classes themselves (ideal) but I a) don't want to have an instance of every class that's used purely to check those conditions and b) I'd make them static, but don't know if it's possible to call a static method dynamically without knowing the class name. I need to allow future plugins to expand the animal classes.

How do you suggest I check such logic?

Comment: Your current design doesn't sound clever. Why would you have 100 different animal classes? How do the classes differ? Why not have one class, that has all the logic, and put all the information in a configuration or properties file?

Comment: I don't have 100 yet though may eventually. Each one contains unique logic about how that entity will behave, in addition to any possible conditions like this. Each's behavior can be very different from the others, and I need to leave it open for a variety of new behaviors. However, those that have expected types of behavior do implement a smaller subset of interfaces.

Comment: @jlordo: Have you taken a gander at the phylogenetic tree lately?  100 categories for animals sounds impossibly small.

Comment: @BotsoNet: If the things you are enumerating are not already well-described and well-known, then Enums sound like a bad choice.  I think you're on the right track with a skeletal implementation based on a base abstract class.  Think carefully about the behaviors that are important to your model ... those should be the interfaces in your contract.  For inspiration, have a look at the hierarchical tree for JavaFX nodes, it's quite complex but achieves something very similar to that which you're describing.

Comment: why will an enum no longer suffice?

Comment: Because trying to pass in that much information for each enum value will be extremely messy, and not easy either. Let's say there are 30 animal classes currently - each needs to define an array of terrain types, array of biome types, min/max numbers for several aspects. Also - there's no way to extend an enum so if we allow plugins or "extra packs" they'd have no ability to add new animals.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a class that stores these meta info.

```
public class Meta

    Class<? extends Animal> clazz;

    boolean hairy;
    // etc



public class Animal

    public abstract Meta getMeta();

class Cat extends Animal

    public static Meta META = new Meta(Cat.class, true, ...);

    public Meta getMeta(){ return META; }
```

The Meta constructor needs to register `this` to some lookup table, so it can be queried later.

Comment: But I would have to make an instance of every single animal class in order to check if it meets current conditions. That's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: can't you loop through all Meta objects, which are preallocated, to find what you want?